# css odd and even on nested elements

Tags: css, nested, selector

https://jsfiddle.net/an5xvdvr/

I want to use css odd and even on a nested html structure.

The first background color should be white, the next black, the next white, the next black and so on until it reaches `Test`.

**html**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      Test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {
  padding: 25px;
  background: #eee;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 2px solid #333;
}
```

**what I tried**

I tried this without success:

```
div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

The depth can be unlimited so I need some magic rule that works for all cases.

Comment: can't be done with pure css unlesss you give classes to the nested divs or add styles for the max number of nests you are going to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div:nth-of-type` selector,select siblings, for example :

```
<div>sibling1</div>
<div>sibling2</div>
<div>sibling3</div>
<div>sibling4</div>
```

in your code all divs are first chidren,so all of them are odd,

if i change your code and add `<div>test2</div>` to your code ,so `<div>test2</div>` and `<div>test</div>` are sibling :

```css
div {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 2px solid #333;
}

 div:nth-of-type(even){
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      Test
      </div>
      <div>
      test2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so in your case ,you can not use nth-of-type but can use of class selector :

```css
div {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 2px solid #333;
}

.even {
  background-color:#fff; 
}
```

```html
<div class="even">
  <div>
    <div class="even">
      <div>
      Test
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do it with CSS `nth`. This does not work on nested element but only on elements inside the same parent.
I did this, it is a little workaround but it works.

[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an5xvdvr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Mate, I don't believe you can do it with `nth` selector because it's nested. I suggest that you use class and make it dynamic **(php/js)** if you're not sure how deep the nest is and filter the class there.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/an5xvdvr/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-black">
  <div class="bg-white">
    <div class="bg-black">
      <div class="bg-white">
      Test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  padding: 25px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 2px solid #333;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: black;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add some Classes using jQuery:

HTML

```html
<div class="first-container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      Test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```html
$( ".first-container div" ).filter( ":even" ).addClass( "odd" );
```

CSS

```css
.odd {
    background: #eee;
}
```