# Is there a CSS selector to exclude a particular branch?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry the title is not particularly explanatory, what I mean is as follows

What I want to achieve with the second CSS selector is "All class b elements that are descendants of class a elements but not descendants of class c elements".  As you can see, the selector I've written actually selects all class b elements, regardless of whether or not they are descendants of class c elements.  (I.e. I want the central div to appear blue rather than red).  Why is my selector not working?

Consider the code in the following:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.a :not(.c) .b {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div class="b">
      <div>
        <div class="c">
          <div>
            <div class="b">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use and/or chain the child combinator (`:not(.c) > .b`) to check against the classes of specific parents, but I don't think there's an easy way to express "none of this element's parents have the class X".

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants explains it, you basically just override the b which are under c. `:not(.c)` also matches the parent of the most inner b, so it is red

Comment: If the structure of the code stays, you could just do `a > div > b` but it's not flexible. If you are in control of the html, I would just add/change the class name for the red box

Comment: Huangism - I see what you mean when you say that :not(.c) also matches the parent of the innermost b, hence it will always be selected using the selector I've written.  I believe you've solved it with the suggestion to override b which are under c.  I can envisage how I will generate that code for the general case, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you are going to make .a, .b and .c differ more later. But if not, perhaps use odd/even class instead? Somewhat similar discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653574/css-odd-and-even-on-nested-elements

Comment: @MikeEustace overriding is usually the easiest way to deal with this but I understand why you want to approach it with a one liner not rule. See the upvoted answer which is also an override which works as well. Mark it as correct if it solves the issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

At least for this case you can do it the other way round. Force the more specific case (.a .c .b) to be blue and set .a .b to red - it will get overruled by the more specific case.
[image]

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.a .c .b {
  background: blue;
  }
  
  .a .b {
    background: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div class="b">
      <div>
        <div class="c">
          <div>
            <div class="b">innermost b
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this CSS sequence you should be ok:
`.a .b .b { background: blue; }`

### DEMO

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.a .b .b {
  background: blue;
}

.a .b {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div class="b">
      <div>
        <div class="c">
          <div>
            <div class="b">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have selected the box that the OP does not want to select and removed the box that the OP wanted haha

Comment: so you want the exact opposit result ?

Comment: I don't want anything, but the OP(original poster) wants the opposite

Comment: Here you go! Let me know

Comment: Well, if you override, it would be better if you just override the b in c. So `.a .b` is red, then `.c .b` is blue. This way you can have b inside of b which is not inside of c. i think the OP is trying to figure a way to do this with not, but there isn't a flexible way to do this with not

Comment: @Huangism No it does not, because `.a .b` override `.c .b` as `.a` is over `.c` Try it yourself

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bdwLqgca/ i have no idea what you are talking about, the only way a b would override c b is if you put a b after c b and since you are trying to override a b, it would not make sense to define c b first